# `ActiveProfiles` annotation not working on Spock tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spock

I have an `application-TEST.yml` file under my classpath and a Spock specification that is annotated as follows.

```
@ActiveProfiles("TEST")
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
class GenerateBillingFileServiceTest extends Specification {
  @Autowired
  AServiceThatUsesProperties aServiceThatUsesProperties

  def "test" {
    //... 
  }
}
```

I want this injected `AServiceThatUsesProperties` to use the values in `application-TEST.yml`. However, this is not the case, and the properties file that is read is the one declared in `application.yml` as `spring.profiles.active: DEVELOPMENT`. Doesn't `@ActiveProfies` override this value? If it doesn't, how do you make a Spock specification use a specific properties file?

Comment: I dont think the problem is spock related..Write a JUnit test and check if the profile is correctly set there.

Comment: Do you've `spock-spring` on test classpath?